# DAX in Power Pivot, fast way to label rows using multiple conditions?

Tags: dax

I have a large table in a Power Pivot data model with 150 million rows. I need a column which simply labels each row based on the values in other columns for that row. I currently have a column which uses the SWITCH function, which takes 1 minute 27 seconds. I want to reduce this time as much as possible. I know it can be faster, because other more advanced columns can compute in 30 seconds whereas this column is doing something really simple. It feels like there's a way of using the FILTER function, because filtering the table manually is under a second? Currently the column uses the following formula:

```
=switch(TRUE(),
Query[modJoinStaticMarker]="Same","Remained in geo and occ",
[modOccJoiners]="Same"&&[modGeoJoiners]="Same","Remained in geo and occ",
[modBrandNew]="Y"&&[modNationalityCategory]="Domestic"&&[modGeoJoiners]="None","Joined NHS newly qualified (UK BN)", 
[modBrandNew]="N"&&[modNationalityCategory]="Domestic"&&[modGeoJoiners]="None","Joined NHS wider labour market (UK non-BN)", 
[modNationalityCategory]="International"&&[modGeoJoiners]="None","Joined NHS international recruitment (non-UK)",
[modOccJoiners]="Same"&&[modGeoJoiners]="Different","Joined from NHS into geo from same occ",
[modOccJoiners]="Different"&&[modGeoJoiners]="Same","Joined from NHS into occ from same geo",
[modOccJoiners]="Different"&&[modGeoJoiners]="Different","Joined from NHS into occ and geo")
```

I've tried IF and AND functions but that produces an identical calculation time. Any help greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Why don't you pre-compute this in PQ?

Comment: @DavideBacci because the main table comes from a SQL connection so I think is necessarily separate from Power Query

Comment: To get the data into Power Pivot data model, you go through PQ. There is a chance you could write the logic in a way that folds back to the server too. If this categorisation is not dynamic (based on slicers), I would do this in PQ.

Comment: Yes unfortunately the whole data model is recalculated by the user, for example the columns GeoJoiners and OccJoiners above are recalculated for the whole table, and then the column above has to recalculate based on those values. For user experience I need this recalculation to be as short as possible

Comment: If you remove the first switch condition `Query[modJoinStaticMarker]="Same","..." ` does it perform faster?

Comment: @SamNseir thanks for this suggestion - I put this in because 90% of the records would return "TRUE" for this condition - ironically I've just tested it and it makes no difference to the time. I'm going to try restructuring the switch function to do nested switches, maybe that will help

Comment: Update: nested switches cut time but only by 3 seconds, to 1 minute 24 seconds

Comment: Try a simple test with `=IF(Query[modJoinStaticMarker]="Same", "Same", "Not same")`. How are you measuring the time it takes? I have feeling the time is a cumulation of all the model calculations together, and not just this one column. If this column is looking at other calculated columns then PBI will need to calculate all preceding calculations etc...

Comment: After reading the above comments, I still have no idea why you can't build this column in PQ. User actions have no effect on calculated columns in any case, so there is no point of using measures in this calculation.

Comment: @RADO in my case the user dynamically alters a lookup table which feeds into the data model which the calculated column must recalculate from

Comment: @samnseir yes this is just this column in isolation. I could do this with a measure but due to the specific requirements of the outputs it has to be a calculated column. Unfortunately I think I’ll just have to accept this as the minimum time